# How to get gmail account info from zapier

Tags: zapier

I want to get profile or demography information from gmail address using zapier. Which action should I use to get required information?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Zapier [Lead Scoring](https://zapier.com/help/lead-score-by-zapier/). That said, in my experience, it usually isn't the best at pulling demographic information from free email accounts.